# Make radio button to be checked using jstl foreach tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a map(`${userOptions}`). For example `{1=B, 2=B, 3=D, 4=A, 5=D}` and `nxtId` contains 1 or 2 or 3 etc.

If `<c:if test="${useroption.key == nxtId}">` returns success check whether the variable `value` contains A or B or C or D. If the value is 'A' appropriate radio button has to be checked and remaining has to be unchecked and so on.

I'm currently using the following:

```
<c:forEach var="useroption" items="${userOptions}">
    <c:out value="${useroption.key == nxtId}"/>
    <script>
        alert("${useroption.key == nxtId}");
    </script>
    <c:if test="${useroption.key == nxtId}">
    <c:set var="check" value="true"/>
    <c:set var="value" value="${useroption.value}"/>
    </c:if>
    <script>
        alert("check value is"+${check});
    </script>
</c:forEach>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${check eq true}">
        <script>
            alert("user option is "+${useroption.value});
        </script>
        <c:forEach var="opt" items="${questionForm}">                                                                                                         
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${value == 'A' }">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left:200px;">                                                                                      
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="${opt.question_id}"/>
                        <h4>Q <c:out value="${opt.question_id}"/>.<c:out value="${opt.question}"/></h4>

                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="A" id="A" checked="checked">

                        A. <c:out value="${opt.option1}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="B" id="B">
                        B.  <c:out value="${opt.option2}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="C" id="C">
                        C.  <c:out value="${opt.option3}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="D" id="D">
                        D.  <c:out value="${opt.option4}"/><br><br>

                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>
                        <c:if test="${opt.question_id > 6}">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                        </c:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                     
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${value == 'B' }">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left:200px;">                                                                                      
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="${opt.question_id}"/>
                        <h4>Q <c:out value="${opt.question_id}"/>.<c:out value="${opt.question}"/></h4>

                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="A" id="A" >

                        A. <c:out value="${opt.option1}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="B" id="B" checked="checked">
                        B.  <c:out value="${opt.option2}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="C" id="C">
                        C.  <c:out value="${opt.option3}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="D" id="D">
                        D.  <c:out value="${opt.option4}"/><br><br>

                        </td>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>
                        <c:if test="${opt.question_id > 6}">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                        </c:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                     
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${value == 'C' }">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left:200px;"> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="${opt.question_id}"/>
                        <h4>Q <c:out value="${opt.question_id}"/>.<c:out value="${opt.question}"/></h4>

                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="A" id="A" >

                        A. <c:out value="${opt.option1}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="B" id="B">
                        B.  <c:out value="${opt.option2}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="C" id="C" checked="checked">
                        C.  <c:out value="${opt.option3}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="D" id="D">
                        D.  <c:out value="${opt.option4}"/><br><br>

                        </td>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>
                        <c:if test="${opt.question_id > 6}">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                        </c:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                     
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${value == 'D' }">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left:200px;">                                                                                      
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="${opt.question_id}"/>
                        <h4>Q <c:out value="${opt.question_id}"/>.<c:out value="${opt.question}"/></h4>

                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="A" id="A" >

                        A. <c:out value="${opt.option1}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="B" id="B" >
                        B.  <c:out value="${opt.option2}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="C" id="C">
                        C.  <c:out value="${opt.option3}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="D" id="D" checked="checked">
                        D.  <c:out value="${opt.option4}"/><br><br>

                        </td>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>
                        <c:if test="${opt.question_id > 6}">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                        </c:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                     
                </c:when>           
                <c:otherwise>
                    <script>
                        alert("hello");
                    </script>
                        <td style="padding-left:200px;">                                                                                      
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="${opt.question_id}"/>
                        <h4>Q <c:out value="${opt.question_id}"/>.<c:out value="${opt.question}"/></h4>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="A" id="A" >

                        A.  <c:out value="${opt.option1}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="B" id="B">
                        B.  <c:out value="${opt.option2}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="C" id="C" >
                        C.  <c:out value="${opt.option3}"/><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="D" id="D">
                        D.  <c:out value="${opt.option4}"/><br><br>
                        </td>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>
                        <c:if test="${opt.question_id > 6}">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                        </c:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                     
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:when>
<c:otherwise>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in without duplicating something like

```
A.  <c:out value="${opt.option1}"/><br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="B" id="B" "${value == 'B' ? 'checked' : ''}">
B.  <c:out value="${opt.option2}"/><br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="C" id="C" "${value == 'C' ? 'checked' : ''}">
C.  <c:out value="${opt.option3}"/><br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="D" id="D" "${value == 'D' ? 'checked' : ''}" >
D.  <c:out value="${opt.option4}"/><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A.  <c:out value="${opt.option1}"/><br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="B" id="B" ${value eq 'B' ? 'checked' : ''}>
B.  <c:out value="${opt.option2}"/><br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="C" id="C" ${value eq 'C' ? 'checked' : ''}>
C.  <c:out value="${opt.option3}"/><br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="D" id="D" ${value eq 'D' ? 'checked' : ''} >
D.  <c:out value="${opt.option4}"/><br><br>
```

from above code you can achive what you want ...
by using JSTL and ternary operator you can achive your functionality with less code 
hope it will help for you